# MLKit object detector is crashing in MLKObjectDetectorOptions

Tags: objective-c, google-mlkit

I am trying to fetch object frames from given image using MKLKIT. But my code is getting crashed
MLKObjectDetectorOptions *options = [[MLKObjectDetectorOptions alloc] init];

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MLKitObjectDetection/MLKitObjectDetection.h>
#import <MLKitObjectDetectionCommon/MLKObjectDetector.h>
#import <MLKitObjectDetection/MLKObjectDetectorOptions.h>
#import <MLKitObjectDetectionCommon/MLKObject.h>
#import <MLKitVision/MLKVisionImage.h>
#import "MLKitObjectDetection.h"

@implementation MLObjectDetection
- (NSMutableArray*)detectFrame:(UIImage*)image{
    NSMutableArray *frames = [NSMutableArray new];
    // Multiple object detection in static images
    MLKObjectDetectorOptions *options = [[MLKObjectDetectorOptions alloc] init];
    options.detectorMode = MLKObjectDetectorModeSingleImage;
    options.shouldEnableMultipleObjects = YES;
    MLKObjectDetector *objectDetector = [MLKObjectDetector objectDetectorWithOptions:options];
    MLKVisionImage *visionImage = [[MLKVisionImage alloc] initWithImage:image];
    visionImage.orientation = image.imageOrientation;
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objects = [objectDetector resultsInImage:visionImage error:&error];
    if (error == nil) {
        return frames;
    }
    if (objects.count == 0) {
      // No objects detected.
    }
    for (MLKObject *object in objects) {
        [frames addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:object.frame]];
    }
    //TODO release memory
    return frames;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

When your code crash, did you try to run your code inside Xcode and look into the console in the debug area to check what error message was printed out there?  Usually that will give you some clue as to what led to the crash.

Based on your code, are you calling the `detectFrame:` method from the main UI thread? The synchronous `MLKObjectDetector#resultsInImage:error:` should never be called from the main UI thread.  This is documented in its [API reference](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/reference/ios/mlkitobjectdetectioncommon/api/reference/Classes/MLKObjectDetector#/c:objc(cs)MLKObjectDetector(im)resultsInImage:error:). You can check out ML Kit's quickstart sample app [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/ios/quickstarts/vision/VisionExampleObjC). It shows how to call both the synchronous `MLKObjectDetector#resultsInImage:error:` API and the asynchronous `MLKObjectDetector#processImage:completion:` API.